# Run a script everyday in django-rest api on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework, scheduled-tasks

I want to run a particular script every day in the morning for my rest api deployed on heroku the script itself it's only a database filler. how can that be done? I forgot to mention that i'm using django rest_framework

Comment: look up `cron`. [This](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) too can be helpful.

Comment: I think you should look into Celery's beat. Integrates well with Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few options. Here's what I do on an app I recently built that regularly scrapes a number of news websites.

In the root of my project I created a `clock.py` and then used `apscheduler` to create a scheduled job. Here's a simple version:

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import Blocking Scheduler
#IMPORTANT! Have to make sure things are working before this starts
from django import setup
setup()

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', days=1):
def timed_job():
    #do something here
    ...
```

I deployed my project on Heroku, so I then went through the process of spinning up a machine to run my `clock.py` file. Once it was up and running the process ran as intended.

There are a number of options besides `interval` you can use to specify when you want the process to run. You can use `chron` style scheduling if you want it to run at specific times and dates. You can read more about that [here](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.2/cronschedule.html#available-fields)